# Backgroun-image not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with background-image not displaying in bootsrap4.

HTML :

```
  <div id="logo_container" class="float-left">
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
#logo_container {
    background-image: url("Images/logo.png");
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

but if i insert an image tag within the HTML, it works. So i believe that the path to my image is correct.

```
  <div id="logo_container" class="float-left">
    <img src="Images/logo.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: *So i believe that the path to my image is correct.* - CSS file and HTML/PHP file in same folder?

Comment: @Sebas HTML (index.html), CSS folder and Images folder are inside the same folder.

Comment: so you need to use the following path on the CSS: `../Images/logo.png`.

Comment: Just tried it and it did not work :(

Comment: Wow it works! now I ran into another problem but yes you solved my initial question :) thanks!